# How to append to dict-like QML-List?

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, qml

I want to dynamicly add key-value-pairs to a list, I tried this code:

```
ListModel{
   id : myListModel
   property var results : {"One": "#ff0000", "Two" : "#ff00ff"}

   ...

   function addstuff() {
      var what = "three";
      results.append ( {what: "#0000ff"} )
  }
}
```

but I get "TypeError: Property 'append' of object [object Object] is not a function". How can I fix it?

Comment: @mike-c  no I didnt ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object.

```
function addstuff() {
    var what = "three";
    results[what] = "#0000ff";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`results` here is a dict. `append` works only on lists/arrays. You can do `results[what]=value`. It will extend your `results`.